# Выборка id строк по максимальному параметру с группировкой

Tags: postgresql, sql

Здравствуйте.

**Ситуация**:
Есть гипотетическая таблица **posts**, содержащая информацию о публикациях. В ней нас интересуют поля **id**(id поста), **author_id**(id автора), **date**(дата создания).

**Задача**: Выбрать для каждого автора **id** последнего поста. Тривиально, казалось бы.

**Путь решения**:

```
select author_id, max(date)
from posts
group by author_id
```

получаем даты последних сообщений для каждого автора. Этого мало, нужны **id** постов.

Если делать так:

```
select author_id, id, max(date)
from posts
group by author_id
```

СуБД ругается на то, что **id** должен обрабатываться агрегатной функцией, либо упоминаться в **GROUP BY**.

Первый вариант нас не устраивает, а второй начинает игнорировать группировку по **id** автора и возвращает все строки из таблицы.

Хочется использовать такое решение:

```
select distinct on (author_id) 
    author_id, id, max(date)
from posts
group by author_id, id
```

Но хоть его выдача и похожа на настоящую, у меня есть сомнения касательно того, принадлежат ли **id** и **date** в итоговой выдаче одной и той же строке (это критичное требование к запросу). Провел несколько проверочных выборок, джойня результат на ту же таблицу и сверяя даты из первой выборки и из таблицы - все вроде бы ок, но сомнения все же не покидают.

**Собственно вопрос**:
Можно ли в приведенном варианте решения верить в то, что СуБД вернет все пары **id**, **date** приданлежащими одной строке, т.е. не дернет **id** из одной и **date** из другой строчки таблицы.

Существует ли какое-то проверенное решение такой задачи. Мнится мне, она довольно таки стандартна.

Comment: С подзапросом не пробовали сделать?

Comment: Например так:

    select author_id, id, date 
      from posts
      where (author_id, date) in (select author_id, max(date)
                                    from posts
                                    group by author_id)

Comment: А не вернет ли он несколько строк для одного автора, в случае если несколько постов было сделано в рамках одной даты?

Плюс, я для наглядности скрыл некоторые условия выборки постов, которые в вашем варианте придется дублировать в обоих запросах.

Но вариант хороший, спасибо.

Comment: >  в случае если несколько постов было сделано в рамках одной даты?

Храните время публикации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT author_id, id, date FROM 
  (SELECT author_id, id, date, rank()  
     OVER (PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY date DESC) FROM posts) AS posts
  WHERE rank = 1;
```

Comment: Что не день, то открытие.

Спасибо.

Comment: Как я понимаю, в варианте из вопроса, гарантии соответствия `id` `date`'у нет?